# Why is hosting a public bitcoind RPC node not more popular?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

Seems like it would be a great way to expand the usability of Bitcoin, i.e. tell your friends to send their transactions to your node when they are not at home and then their client software only needs to manage simple wallet / key operations. Curious why this is not common practice.

Comment: Are you suggesting SPV wallets or some sort of ultrathin  RPC client to a multiuser wallet node?

Comment: More the latter. Probably even a Bitcoind node compiled without the wallet. I'm imagining many unrelated users, using a very thin client just doing wallet operations and using the Node to rely on for consensus and sending transactions, etc. I understand this is not ideal from a decentralization perspective, but it seems like a worthwhile compromise, for the convenience, if you trust the Node provider.

Answer (score 3):

The Bitcoin Core RPC interface is a private interface not suitable to be exposed publicly or accessed by untrusted parties.

On the other hand it is quite popular for people to host public or semi-public Electrum servers. This way stranger or friends can point their wallet to this server to fetch information about their coins from the Bitcoin network.

Answer (score -1):

What does it mean semi-public ?

What a configuration should I do on the server for public / semi-public / private?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: This is another question posted as an answer.